# Are cstrings multibyte

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm somewhat confused about CStrings. From what I gather, when UNICODE is defined, CStrings use CStringW and are encoded in "UTF-16". My question is, are they actually implemented as multi-byte per the UTF-16 specification? Do they have any support for the supplementary plane?

Comment: Most `CString` methods don't care; they just work with a sequence of `wchar_t`s. Methods like `Collate` call into Windows API functions, which do handle surrogate pairs correctly.

Comment: Windows switched from UCS-2 to UTF-16 in Windows 2000.  All Win32 Unicode APIs that care about codepoints support supplementary planes via UTF-16 surrogate pairs.